# How to check if a composite primary key values exist in sql table using powershell?

Tags: sql, powershell

I have 2 primary keys in an sql table, say for eg: ApID and AnID. I want to update the sql table (dbo.ApAn) if the particular composite primary key values exist or else insert new values into the table **through powershell**

**How can I get the sql table's composite primary keys in powershell?** using a join or something?

Something like:

```
IF (ApId_AnID-eq 0) { 
#SQL INSERT CODE
} else { 
#SQL UPDATE CODE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql server console client `sqlcmd` or `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx.

For specific queries see [Retrieving column information (composite key) in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662587/retrieving-column-information-composite-key-in-sql)