# How to get a list of tables with composite primary key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I create a query that gives me a list of tables with composite primary key in SQL Server? Maybe using sys.tables or information_schema.tables or something else?

Comment: What have you tried. Where have you searched. The inter webs is full of this stuff... You should know better.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can dig that info up in `information_schema.table_constraints` and `information_schema.constraint_column_usage` tables, by checking for multiple rows of `PRIMARY KEY` constraints on a table, something like:

```
SELECT col.table_name 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc 
JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage col
  ON col.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
 AND col.table_name = tc.table_name
 AND tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
GROUP BY col.table_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1162/1).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use eigher schema table or columns table. Here is it.

```
SELECT K.TABLE_CATALOG, 
   K.TABLE_NAME, 
   K.COLUMN_NAME, 
   K.ORDINAL_POSITION     FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE K 
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC 
     ON K.TABLE_CATALOG = TC.TABLE_CATALOG 
        AND K.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA 
        AND K.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Refer link - [Retrieving column information (composite key) in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662587/retrieving-column-information-composite-key-in-sql)

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/04/sql-server-2005-find-tables-with-primary-key-constraint-in-database/